# External CSS and JS files not getting included in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project where I need to include some of the external libraries and http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ (FancyBox) is one of them.

I downloaded the library and put the folder in my project folder and used the commands to include the external files as given in the website, but in the console it shows that the files are not included.

Then I changed the file names to what is the actual name (eg : remove the ?v=1.0.5 part from the files), but even then it is showing that the files have not been included. I need to use this library but really don't know why the files are not being included.

```
<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>>
```

PS : My downloaded fancybox folder is in the project folder only.

What could be the possible reason for this problem?

Comment: Remove the preceding `/` and see if that works `fancybox/...`.

Comment: where is your index.php or the file where you entered these scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fancybox folder is in the root directory of project then you don't need to add `\`

just start path with `fancybox/` instead of `/fancybox/`